# How do I draw the attached picture in Latex

Tags: tables

I need help for drawing such a table in latex

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

below is a barebones solution and a nicer solution. To make it look prettier, you might want to look at packages like multirow and booktabs, and tabularx. You can find some tips for making nice tables [here](https://inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf).

**Your Table**

```
\documentclass[landscape, 10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Your table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Method  &   CP  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Parameters}   & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Standard Error} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{P-values} ``\\``
    \hline
            &       & $\omega$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\omega$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\omega$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ ``\\``
    \hline
    BAE     &       & 7.1$e$-3 & 6.3$e$-1 & 1.4$e$-1    & 2.2$e$-4 & 2.2$e$-2 & 5.1$e$-2    & 4.2$e$-3 & 1.0$e$-1 & 6.8$e$-3 ``\\``
    QML     &   A   & 7.1$e$-3 & 7.1$e$-1 & 1.0$e$-8    & 1.9$e$-3 & 1.1$e$-1 & 1.1$e$-1    & 2.2$e$-4 & 8.8$e$-11 & 1.0$e$0 ``\\`` 
    SVM     &       & 7.0$e$-3 & 6.5$e$-1 & 1.4$e$-1    & 2.0$e$-4 & 4.5$e$-2 & 4.9$e$-2    & 4.0$e$-3 & 0.9$e$-1 & 6.0$e$-4 ``\\``
    \hline
    BAE     &       & 8.9$e$-3 & 5.4$e$-1 & 2.6$e$-1    & 7.0$e$-4 & 4.0$e$-2 & 4.0$e$-2    & 3.3$e$-3 & 1.0$e$-1 & 4.0$e$-3 ``\\``
    QML     &   B   & 7.4$e$-3 & 5.1$e$-1 & 4.1$e$-1    & 5.5$e$-3 & 1.4$e$-1 & 2.9$e$-1    & 4.3$e$-1 & 5.3$e$-4 & 1.6$e$-1 ``\\``
    SVM     &       & 6.5$e$-3 & 5.2$e$-1 & 3.0$e$-1    & 5.0$e$-4 & 3.8$e$-2 & 3.5$e$-2    & 2.9$e$-3 & 4.5$e$-5 & 2.4$e$-4 ``\\``
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Nice Table**

```
\documentclass[landscape, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Nicer table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lc*{3}{r@{$e$}l}c*{3}{r@{$e$}l}c*{3}{r@{$e$}l}@{}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Method} &   \multirow{2}{*}{CP} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Parameters}    && \multicolumn{6}{c}{Standard Error} && \multicolumn{6}{c}{P-values} ``\\``
                        \cmidrule{3-8}                  \cmidrule{10-15}                    \cmidrule{17-22}
            &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\omega$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\alpha$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\beta$} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\omega$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\alpha$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\beta$}    && \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\omega$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\alpha$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\beta$} ``\\``
    \midrule
    BAE     &\multirow{3}{*}{A} & 7.1&-3 & 6.3&-1 & 1.4&-1  && 2.2&-4 & 2.2&-2 & 5.1&-2 && 4.2&-3 & 1.0&-1 & 6.8&-3 ``\\``
    QML     &       & 7.1&-3 & 7.1&-1 & 1.0&-8  && 1.9&-3 & 1.1&-1 & 1.1&-1 && 2.2&-4 & 8.8&-11 & 1.0&0 ``\\``
    SVM     &       & 7.0&-3 & 6.5&-1 & 1.4&-1  && 2.0&-4 & 4.5&-2 & 4.9&-2 && 4.0&-3 & 0.9&-1 & 6.0&-4 ``\\``
    \midrule
    BAE     &\multirow{3}{*}{B} & 8.9&-3 & 5.4&-1 & 2.6&-1  && 7.0&-4 & 4.0&-2 & 4.0&-2 && 3.3&-3 & 1.0&-1 & 4.0&-3 ``\\``
    QML     &       & 7.4&-3 & 5.1&-1 & 4.1&-1  && 5.5&-3 & 1.4&-1 & 2.9&-1 && 4.3&-1 & 5.3&-4 & 1.6&-1 ``\\``
    SVM     &       & 6.5&-3 & 5.2&-1 & 3.0&-1  && 5.0&-4 & 3.8&-2 & 3.5&-2 && 2.9&-3 & 4.5&-5 & 2.4&-4 ``\\``
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**This is how the two tables look like**

[image: Resulting tables]

Comment: +1 for adding the typographically pleasing "nice table" variant.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What if I would like to interchange the (nice table)'s first and second column, to read as follows:
CP      Method     ........    ..........      ....... 
Thanks

Comment: The columns are delimited by the ampersand symbol (&). So if you want to switch the 1st and 2nd columns, all you have to do is to put everything that is before the first "&" (that is, the old first column) behind it and everything that used to be between the first and second "&" (old second column) before the first "&", like so:
old: \multirow{2}{*}{Method} &   \multirow{2}{*}{CP} & ...
new: \multirow{2}{*}{CP} & \multirow{2}{*}{Method} &   ...